# R: reordering rows within a data frame

Tags: r

It is hard to explain with words so I'll put a concrete example.

My data frame looks like this:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
1  a  b  c  d  0  0  0  0
2  e  f  g  h  0  0  0  0
3  i  j  k  l  0  0  0  0
.  .  .  .  .  0  0  0  0  (and so on)
0  0  0  0  0  1  a  g  c
0  0  0  0  0  1  a  h  c
0  0  0  0  0  .  .  .  .  (and so on)
0  0  0  0  0  2  u  i  l
0  0  0  0  0  2  k  m  n
0  0  0  0  0  .  .  .  .  (and so on)
0  0  0  0  0  3  u  j  v
0  0  0  0  0  3  z  a  r
0  0  0  0  0  .  .  .  .  (and so on)
```

What I would like is:

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
1  a  b  c  d  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  1  a  g  c
0  0  0  0  0  1  a  h  c
0  0  0  0  0  .  .  .  .  (and so on)
2  e  f  g  h  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  2  u  i  l
0  0  0  0  0  2  k  m  n
0  0  0  0  0  .  .  .  .  (and so on)
3  i  j  k  l  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  0  0  3  u  j  v
0  0  0  0  0  3  z  a  r
0  0  0  0  0  .  .  .  .  (and so on)
```

Note: `unique(df$V1) = unique(df$V6)`

Comment: What are those `.` ?  Is it NA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an option:

```
df[order(pmax(df$V1, df$V6)),]
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9
# 1  1  a  b  c  d  0  0  0  0
# 4  0  0  0  0  0  1  a  g  c
# 5  0  0  0  0  0  1  a  h  c
# 2  2  e  f  g  h  0  0  0  0
# 6  0  0  0  0  0  2  u  i  l
# 7  0  0  0  0  0  2  k  m  n
# 3  3  i  j  k  l  0  0  0  0
# 8  0  0  0  0  0  3  u  j  v
# 9  0  0  0  0  0  3  z  a  r
```